# Array will not work in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net

```
 Dim Cans(7) As String
Dim money As Decimal

Public Sub Main()
    Cans(0) = "Pepsi"
    Cans(1) = "Pepsi MAX"
    Cans(2) = "Sprite"
    Cans(3) = "Mountain Dew"
    Cans(4) = "Fanta"
    Cans(5) = "Coca Cola"
    Cans(6) = "Coke Diet"
    Cans(7) = "Coke Vanilla"

End Sub


Private Sub ButtonPepsi_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonPepsi.Click
    If money >= 0.8 Then
        money = money - 0.8
        TextBoxItem.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        TextBoxItem.Text = "You brought a " & Cans(0)
        TextboxCredit.Text = "£" & money
    End If
End Sub
```

Every time I click the button to buy a pepsi, it just says in the textbox "You bought a " and it should say "Pepsi" but it does not work. Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: What is main()? It is a console or a windows forms application?

Comment: It is a sub to declare the objects of the arrays. It is also a WindowsFormApplication

Comment: OK, in this case, nobody seems to be calling main(). The Heinzi's answer is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB.NET has many methods of starting your application. Which one is used can be set in the project properties. The most common ones are:

**Sub Main**: Here, a sub **Main** in a module is called. Then, it's the sub's responsibility to start forms that should be shown.

**Start Form**: This is probably the option you are using. A specific form is opened and shown to the user. No Sub Main is executed.

How do you solve your problem? If you want to initialize the array *when the window is opened*, just use the `Form.Load` event for that:

```
Public Sub Form_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Cans(0) = "Pepsi"
    Cans(1) = "Pepsi MAX"
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: I keep getting NullReferenceException error on the object for the arrays. Any way to resolve this?

Comment: @user3392480: You should not be, array is initialized, so this `Cans(7)` creates an array of 8 empty elements. As opposed to this `Cans()` which is an empty array reference. Please elaborate in your question.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. I had 'Public Variable Cans() as String()' from a previous attempt to fix it. This caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Main is never called, that's why your array elements are all empty string. I think you are mixing console and windows applications. You can place a call to Main in Sub New, after InitializeComponent. Or better, move all that code after InitializeComponent, to avoid confusion.

Or just declare your `Cans` array like this:

```
Dim Cans() As String = {"Pepsi", ..., "Coke Vanilla"}
```

Then you don't need `Main` at all.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: Thank you Steven, joining the mod ranks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Private Sub ButtonPepsi_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonPepsi.Click

Main()
If money >= 0.8 Then
    money = money - 0.8
    TextBoxItem.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
    TextBoxItem.Text = "You brought a " & Cans(0)
    TextboxCredit.Text = "£" & money
End If 
End Sub
```